# Http 500 Internal Server Error in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

```
<%@page import="javax.naming.*,javax.sql.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<html>
    <head><title>Displaying Employee List</title></head>
    <body>
        <% String message,Seat_no,Name,ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,ans5;
        int Total=0;
        java.sql.Connection connect;
        java.sql.Statement stmt=null;
        java.sql.ResultSet rs=null;
        String url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Senor [root on APP]";
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        connect=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","root");
        message="Thank you";
        Seat_no=request.getParameter("Seat_no");
        Name=request.getParameter("Name");
        ans1=request.getParameter("group1");
        ans2=request.getParameter("group2");
        ans3=request.getParameter("group3");
        ans4=request.getParameter("group4");
        ans5=request.getParameter("group5");
        if(ans1.equals("True"))
            Total+=2;
        if(ans2.equals("False"))
            Total+=2;
        if(ans3.equals("True"))
            Total+=2;
        if(ans4.equals("False"))
            Total+=2;
        if(ans5.equals("False"))
            Total+=2;
        stmt=connect.createStatement();
        String query="Insert into she(Seat_no,Name,Total)values("+Seat_no+","+Name+","+Total+")";
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        stmt.close();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body bgcolor=cyan>");
        out.println("<center>");
        out.println("<h1>"+message+"</h1>\n");
        out.println("<h3>Your results stored in our database</h3>");
        out.println("<table border=5>");
        java.sql.Statement stmt2=connect.createStatement();
        String query1="Select * from she";
        rs=stmt2.executeQuery(query1);
        out.println("<th>"+"Seat_no"+"</th>");
        out.println("<th>"+"Name"+"</th>");
        out.println("<th>"+"Marks"+"</th>");
        while(rs.next())
        {
            out.println("<tr>");
            out.println("<td>"+rs.getString(1)+"</td>");
            out.println("<td>"+rs.getString(2)+"</td>");
            out.println("<td>"+rs.getString(3)+"</td>");
            out.println("</tr>");
        }
        out.println("</table>");
        if(rs!=null)
            rs.close();
        if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
        if(connect!=null)
            connect.close();
        out.println("</center>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
        Total=0;






        %>
</body>
</html>




This is the jsp program i used and here is the html code for it

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Database test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
        <form action="Action.jsp" method="post">
            <div align="left">
                <br>
            </div>
            <b>
                Seat number:</b>
            <input type="text" name="Seat_no">
            <div align="right">
                <b>Name:</b><input type="text" name="Name" size="50"><br>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <b>1.Im intelligent.</b><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="group1" value="True">True
            <input type="radio" name="group1" value="False">False<br>
            <b>2.Im a dog.</b><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="group2" value="True">True
            <input type="radio" name="group2" value="False">False<br>
            <b>3.Fast and steady wins.</b><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="group3" value="True">True
            <input type="radio" name="group3" value="False">False<br>
            <b>4.Be true.</b><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="group4" value="True">True
            <input type="radio" name="group4" value="False">False<br>
            <b>5.Strike the iron while it is hot.</b><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="group5" value="True">True
            <input type="radio" name="group5" value="False">False<br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <center>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br><br>
            </center>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I could run my HTML program but when i click the Submit button i am directed to the error page. I've added the necessary JAR folders and still don't get the output.Stuck up with this for more than 4 days!I tried the same program around 3 months back and it worked out just fine! Where am i going wrong?

Comment: you should look into the logfile of your web server to find a stracktrace of the error

Comment: Usually, the stack trace also appears in the console output as well

Comment: It says that my database was not found.I assumed after spending time on googling, that it was because my database folder wasnt inside my project.How do i change the path and bring it from the netbeans_derby folder to my project?

Comment: exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: The connection was refused because the database Senor [root on APP] was not found.
root cause

java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: The connection was refused because the database Senor [root on APP] was not found.
root cause

org.apache.derby.client.am.DisconnectException: The connection was refused because the database Senor [root on APP] was not found.
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 logs.